# emberjs: how to trigger a custom event in a View

Tags: events, view, ember.js, router, custom-events

I would like to turn a primitive event (a click) into a semantic event, like "deleteTodo"
This is described [here](http://emberjs.com/guides/views/), but not how to implement :(
I have the following code:

```
App.TodoView = Em.View.extend({
    click: function(e) {
        this.trigger("deleteTodo");
    }
});

App.Router.map(function(match) {
    match('/').to('index');
});

App.IndexRoute = Ember.Route.extend({
    deleteTodo: function(e) {
        // this code is never executed :(
    }
}) ;
```

After I perform the 'click', I see that the TodoView click function is called, but not the deleteTodo function from the IndexRoute. Any suggestions what might go wrong here ?

CHeers

Answer (score 5):

You can use this.get("controller").send("deleteTodo"). This will send a message to the controller, if the controller doesn't handle deleteTodo it will bubble to the router and be handled there.

```
click: function(e) {
    this.get('controller').send("deleteTodo");
}
```

In your router you will also need to define the event:

```
events: {
  doStuff: function(e) {
    alert("Do stuff") ;    
  }
}
```

http://jsfiddle.net/9Xasr/7/

I would typically do record deletion in the controller. Seems like putting that in a router event would not be ideal.

Comment: I can't get it to work, so I've created a jsfiddle here: http://jsfiddle.net/jeanluca/9Xasr/6/ Any suggestions ?

Comment: Its not this.get('controller').send('deleteTodo') but to send the event to the router we have to use the target property in the controller. e.g. this.get('controller.target').send('deleteTodo'). I have update the fiddle here: http://jsfiddle.net/9Xasr/9/

Comment: When you send an event to a controller it bubbles to the router. I prefer to send to controller in case it wants to handle the event and if I ignore it then it bubbles to the router.