# EmberJs: Custom event not received in the Router

Tags: ember.js, eventtrigger, custom-event

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [emberjs: how to trigger a custom event in a View](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/14634622/emberjs-how-to-trigger-a-custom-event-in-a-view)

I've created a jsfiddle to demonstrate the issue. WHen you click in the view (on the text) you will see in the console that the view receives the click. But when I create a custom event and trigger it, its not received in the router:

```
App.IndexView = Em.View.extend({
    click: function(e) {
        console.log("CLICK");
        this.get("controller").send("doStuff");
}
});

App.IndexRoute = Em.Route.extend({
    ....
    doStuff: function(e) {
       alert("Do stuff") ;    
    }
});
```

Here is a complete working example too http://jsfiddle.net/jeanluca/9Xasr/6/

Any suggestions ?

Cheers

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You are calling `doStuff()` of the controller for the App.IndexView, but you define `doStuff` inside the Route. You should move it into `App.IndexController`:

```
App.IndexController = Em.Controller.extend({
    doStuff: function(e) {
       alert("Do stuff") ;    
    }
});
```

Fiddle: http://jsfiddle.net/8k4PE/

On the other hand, if you want the route to receive the event:

```
<script type="text/x-handlebars" data-template-name="navigation">
    <span {{action "doStuff}}>Sidebar</span>
</script>

App.IndexRoute = Em.Route.extend({
    //...
    events: {
      doStuff: function(e) {
         alert("Do stuff") ;    
      }
    }
});
```

Comment: From the documentation: These semantic events are sent to your application's router (See the intro on views), so they should travel to your router, I would say!

Comment: @JeanlucaScaljeri but `doStuff` is not an event handler function. You just call it from the actual event handler (which by default is the `click` function in the view). If you want define `doStuff` as an event handler use `{{action "doStuff"}}` on the target element.

Comment: ok, now I see. Just curious, is it possible to trigger the doStuff event manually ? or should this always be done as you just described!

Comment: @JeanlucaScaljeri I'm not sure what you mean "manually"

Comment: Triggering the event within the view class as described above: this.get("controller").send("doStuff"); or this.trigger("doStuff") ; Or maybe this.triggerAction("doStuff") ?

Comment: let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/23898/discussion-between-jeanluca-scaljeri-and-panagiotis-panagi)

Comment: @JeanlucaScaljeri you can definitely do that. Also take a look at http://emberjs.com/api/classes/Ember.TargetActionSupport.html